# Read file to ArrayList and to Object

Tags: java, arraylist, filereader

I currently have the following code to read data from a txt file to an object. However the ArrayList doesn't work properly.

```
public static void load_Recipes() {
    // Read file and load data into ingredient object
    String[] current_line = new String[7];

    // Variables for the ingredient object attributes
    int recipeID;
    String recipeName;
    int recipePrepTime;
    String recipeURL;
    String recipeCuisine;
    String recipeType;
    double recipeRating;
    String recipeIngredients;
    ArrayList<Integer> recipeContainsID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //String cleanString[] = new String[20];
    //ArrayList<String> stringInt = new ArrayList<String>();


    try {
        int i = 0;
        BufferedReader my_reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("recipes.txt"));
        String input_line; //variable to read line by line
        while( (input_line=my_reader.readLine()) != null){
            current_line = input_line.split("\t"); //split the line at the tab
            recipeID = Integer.parseInt(current_line[0]);
            recipeName = current_line[1];
            recipePrepTime = Integer.parseInt(current_line[2]); 
            recipeURL = current_line[3];
            recipeCuisine = current_line[4];
            recipeType = current_line[5];
            recipeRating = Double.parseDouble(current_line[6]); 
            recipeIngredients = current_line[7];
            System.out.println("The current value of recipeIngredients is: " + recipeIngredients); // Checking current value, removed when working
            String clean1[] = recipeIngredients.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|","").split(",");

            for(int j = 0; j < clean1.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(clean1[j] + ", "); // Checking the current value, removed when working
                recipeContainsID.add(Integer.parseInt(clean1[j]));
            }

            // test
            all_recipes[i] = new Recipe(recipeID, recipeName, recipePrepTime, recipeURL, recipeCuisine, recipeType, recipeRating, recipeContainsID);
            System.out.println("Next object.");
            i++;
        }
        my_reader.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("can't read file");
    }
}
```

The text file contains the following:

```
1   Spaghetti   60  wwww.cooking.nl italiaans   tussengerecht   1.0 [1,2,3,4]
2   Lasagna 30  wwww.cooking.nl italiaans   tussengerecht   3.2 [5,6,7,8]
3   Groente 40  wwww.cooking.nl italiaans   hoofdgerecht    3.1 [7,3,8,4]
4   Risotto 90  wwww.cooking.nl italiaans   hoofdgerecht    4.1 [3,2,5,4]
```

Whenever I tried to write the last integers between [] to an object ArrayList they get added all to 1 list. The output in the console:

```
1   Spaghetti   60  wwww.cooking.nl itialiaans  tussengerecht   1.0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 3, 8, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4]
2   Lasagna 30  wwww.cooking.nl itialiaans  tussengerecht   3.2 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 3, 8, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4]
3   Groente 40  wwww.cooking.nl itialiaans  hoofdgerecht    3.1 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 3, 8, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4]
4   Risotto 90  wwww.cooking.nl itialiaans  hoofdgerecht    4.1 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 3, 8, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4]
```

And the code for the printing:

```
public static void view_Recipes() {
    for(int i=0;i<Recipe.getNum_recipes();i++)
        System.out.println(all_recipes[i].getRecipeID() + "\t" + all_recipes[i].getRecipeName() + "\t" + all_recipes[i].getRecipePrepTime() + "\t" + all_recipes[i].getRecipeURL() + "\t" + all_recipes[i].getRecipeCuisine() + "\t" + all_recipes[i].getRecipeType() + "\t" + all_recipes[i].getRecipeRating() + "\t" + all_recipes[i].getRecipeContainsID());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the arraylist before you process the next line of recipe i.e. inside of while loop. Otherwise the same arraylist keeps getting accumulated and because it is the same object it will contain the same values for every line.

Move this line

`ArrayList<Integer> recipeContainsID = new ArrayList<Integer>();` inside while loop.

`while( (input_line=my_reader.readLine()) != null) {
  ArrayList<Integer> recipeContainsID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ....
   ...
   ...`

Comment: Thanks! Shame couldn't figure that one out myself.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `ArrayList` `receipeContainsID` is outside the loop iteration.

`ArrayList<Integer> recipeContainsID = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Move it inside the loop while reading each line and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a 2 dimensional `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> recipeContainsID`and keep a list  for every recipe, you are adding all of them to the same ArrayList...You must be carefull to initialize a new ArrayList for every new recipe...

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to assignments in while loop. Each variable except `recipeContainsID` gets updated there. For primitives, you are assigning new values and for String objects, you are assigning references to newly created instances (note that Strings are immutable).

Hence, if you want values to be added to separate lists, you need to create a new list for each processed line. If you don't want to make any changes to these lists, you can use `Arrays.asList()` method to create them.

`recipeContainsID = Arrays.asList(clean1);`